# Phusion Passenger configuration: How passenger_min_instances affects the sub-URI setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, rack

We are setting up multiple `sub-URI` (3 of them) in `passenger` config. We want to ensure that for each `sub-uri`, we have `at least one instanc`e running all the time. How can we use the `passenger_min_instances`
flag to do that. If I assign this flag to equal 3, is this right? Does it mean there are 3 instances for each `sub-uri instance` running ALL THE TIME after first visit to the server? Thanks.

Here is the setup in nginx server block:

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name 176.95.25.193;
       root /var/www;
       passenger_enabled on;
       rails_env production;
       passenger_base_uri /nbhy;
       passenger_base_uri /bt;
       passenger_base_uri /byop;
       passenger_min_instances 2;
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put configuration for a specific base URI in a location block. Like this:

```
location ~ ^/nbhy(/.*|$) {
    ...
    passenger_min_instances 2;
}
location ~ ^/bt(/.*|$) {
    ...
    passenger_min_instances 3;
}
```

Comment: Hi Hongli, what's the use of ~ ^/nbhy(/.*|$)? Just exact match for suburi /nbhy?

Comment: Yes. "location /nbhy" matches all URLs that start with /nbhy, including /nbhythisisnotwhatyouwant. You want it to match /nbyh exactly, and also /nbyh/whatever.